# __m128i initializers and _mm_madd_epi16: What is the result?

Tags: visual-c++, intel, sse, intrinsics

I tried the following code:

```
__m128i x = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
__m128i y = { 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80};

__m128i z = _mm_madd_epi16(x, y);
```

The result is:
`z = {6244, 201, -17692, 1006, 0,0,0,0}`

But the first element should be `1*10 + 2*20 = 50`.

Can you please explain the result I got ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the initial values.

```
__m128i x = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
```

Those `__m128i` initializers don't do what you think they do.
To begin with they do not even compile on most compilers, except MSVC. In the case of MSVC, what happened here is equivalent to:

```
__m128i x = _mm_setr_epi8( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 );
```

Which isn't what you meant.

The fix is simple: use the proper `set` intrinsic, in this case `_mm_setr_epi16` for 16-bit elements.  (Or `_mm_set_epi16` if you want to give the highest one on the left, on the side a left-shift would shift towards.)

Remember that C initializer lists for structs / unions / arrays can have fewer elements with the rest being implicit zeros.  So the number of explicit elements can't imply which element width you meant.  The intrinsics API uses `_mm_set` intrinsics instead of bare initializer lists because the same type can hold different numbers of elements.

You can check the elements of a `__m128i` with a debugger.

Comment: Hi harold. Thank you very much. with _mm_set_epi16 I got the right results.